# Distinguished field on a web service (BizTalk)

Tags: web-services, biztalk, field

How do you access a field in the message returned by a web service call ?

I found Richard Seroters [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/richardbpi/archive/2006/11/09/setting-promoted-distinguished-fields-on-biztalk-web-messages.aspx) but it says to drill through the Reference.map to the Reference.xsd ... 

 - problem is, I've not got a Reference.xsd 

 - I do have the Reference.map, and the child Reference.odx

 - I also have the wsdl, but not the disco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that ...

*If the method includes something other than primitive data types, there will also be a Reference.xsd file under Reference.map.  After adding this reference, we’ll be able to create messages to communicate with the web service defining the type as a Web Message and choosing the appropriate schema.*

and the web services I'm talking to just return a string, albeit actually XML

From this [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20201020175924/http://geekswithblogs.net/evankoch/archive/2007/09/26/115647.aspx)

Comment: And a few more links ...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561724.aspx
http://www.webservertalk.com/archive178-2005-5-1076227.html

And a potential solution, use the WCF BasicHttp Adapter
http://www.digitaldeposit.net/saravana/post/2007/05/31/BizTalk-2006-R2-consume-an-ASMX-webservice-using-WCF-BasicHttp-adapter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am confused as to why you do not have an XSD that was generated by the BizTalk proxy?  You can of course tag the generated proxy code class with attributes that will allow you to set the field as a promoted property or a distinguisted field.  If you do not have either I am not sure you can do it.  Take a look [here](http://blogdoc.biztalk247.com/article.aspx?page=a4f1434e-2dab-463d-963c-d3308ab13d58).

-Bryan